# android studio java Error:Execution failed for task

Tags: java, android, android-studio, build, apk

when i go to generate APK 
he give me this error

Error:Execution failed for task ':android:dexRelease'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_60\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Comment: You are probably including two different versions of the same dependency.

Comment: you can explain? i dont understand

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in `gradle` file

```
defaultConfig {        
    // Enabling multidex support.
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: include 'desktop', 'core', 'android', 'BaseGameUtils' ؟

Comment: add it in build.gradle file in your project